# How to add a text file into a zipped file created from a requests call in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, zip

I made a request and be able to access and store a zipped file downloaded from a page. The zipped file contains multiple text files within, such as `text1.txt`, `text2.txt`, etc.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://somewhere.com/download.zip', stream=True)

handle = open('store_locally.zip', "wb")

for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    handle.write(chunk)
handle.close
```

However, I would like to add an extra .txt file named `lastupdated.txt`. Code as:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://somewhere.com/download.zip', stream=True)

handle = open('store_locally.zip', "wb")

for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    handle.write(chunk)

f=open("lastupdated.txt","w+")
f.write('2019-02-12')
handle.write(f)

handle.close
```

This gave me an error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\main.py", line 55, in <module>
    handle.write(f)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

It does create the `lastupdated.txt` file in the same directory of `main.py`, but this is not what I want, I would like it to be created within the zipped file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're just opening a new file (`lastupdated.txt`) and writing to it, it has no relationship to the zip. After you write the zip to disk and close it, you can use the `zipfile` module to add the new file to it:

```
import zipfile

import requests

outfile = "stored_locally.zip"
r = requests.get("http://somewhere.com/download.zip", stream=True)

with open(outfile, "wb") as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(2048):
        fd.write(chunk)

with zipfile.ZipFile(outfile, "a") as z:
    z.writestr("lastupdated.txt", "2019-02-12")
```

Edit: Downloading and modifying the file in memory, without writing to disk:

```
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

import requests

r = requests.get("http://somewhere.com/download.zip")
f = BytesIO(r.content)

with zipfile.ZipFile(f, "a") as z:
    z.writestr("lastupdated.txt", "2019-02-12")
```

Comment: Is there a way to directly create and write that new text file in `fd`, without first finish creating the zipped file then reopening it?

Comment: @KubiK888 I added to my answer